# How to Choose date from Datepicker Using Codeception

Tags: codeception

I want to select a custom date from Datepicker tool.. so anybody know that how to choose date in Codeception(follow PHP syntax).
Note: We are using Selenium stand alone server for same.
Please help me out on this issue

Answer (score 0):

If faker lib does not help and you have to actually click on date picker instead of typing a date, you could do something in this logic perhaps:

```
 $this->click(your_locator_for_datepicker_button);
 $this->clickDateOnDatePicker($date)
```

where clickDateOnDatePicker can be =>

```
public function clickDateOnDatePicker($date)
    {
        list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
        $element = sprintf(your_locator_for_datepicker_button_within_modal, $month - 1, $year, ltrim($day, '0'));
        $this->clickElement($element);
        $this->waitForElementNotVisible($element);
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1: **Define your locator of date picker**

e.g.

```
public static $datePickerDate = '//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]//tbody//td[@data-month="%s" and @data-year="%s"]/a[normalize-space(.)="%s"]';
```

## 2: Define a step method

```
    public function clickDateOnDatePicker($date, $inputElement = '')
    {
        if (!empty($inputElement)) {
            $this->click($inputElement);
        }
        list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
        $element = sprintf(BasePage::$datePickerDate, $month - 1, $year, ltrim($day, '0'));
        $this->clickElement($element);
        $this->waitForElementNotVisible($element);
        return $this;
    }
```

## 3: In your Cest file use it like:

```
public function myTest($date)
{
    .
    .
    .
    $this->clickDateOnDatePicker($date);
    return $this;
}
```